# C# List with Unique data based on the Date

Tags: c#, sql-server, list

I have a table that has the sales of the current month in order by how many time a dish has being sold in each day of the month but in this order:

```
[Dishes]
Fecha                       |   Pdv    | Pla_ID  |  Quantity |  Price   | Total |
===============================================================================
2016-11-03 00:00:00.000        REST      65        4           50.00     200.00
2016-11-05 00:00:00.000        REST      65        1           50.00      50.00
2016-11-07 00:00:00.000        REST      65        7           50.00     350.00
2016-11-03 00:00:00.000        REST      70        6           100.00    600.00
2016-11-04 00:00:00.000        REST      70        7           100.00    700.00
2016-11-05 00:00:00.000        REST      70        1           100.00    100.00
2016-11-06 00:00:00.000        REST      70        3           100.00    300.00
2016-11-07 00:00:00.000        REST      70        1           100.00    100.00
```

Im looking for a way to save the records into a list but with the date being a coulmn for each day of the month, and the Quantity values getting asigned to the day in wich they where sold like this
In this Order:

```
[Result]
|PDV|Pla_Id|Price|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|Quantity_Total|Total| 
========================================================================================================================
|REST| 65  |  50 |0|0|4|0|1|0|7|0|0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|       12      | 600 |
|REST| 70  |  50 |0|0|6|7|1|3|1|0|0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|       18      | 1800 |
```

"Pla_Id=65" 
Sold 4 times the 3rd of november , 1 time the fifth and 7 tiemes the seventh total of 12 times in the month of november

"Pla_id=70"
Sold 6 times the 3rd of november , 7 time the fourth, 1 time the fifth, 3 times the six and 1 time the seventh giving a total of 18 times in the month of november

So my list would look like this:

```
["REST","65","50","0","0","4","0","1","0","7","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","12","$600.00"]
["REST","70","100","0","0","6","7","1","3","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","18","$1800.00"]
```

This is my current Aproach

```
foreach (var item in db.Dishes)
        {
            List<string> listItem = new List<string>();
            decimal costo = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                var value = 0;
                if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = (int)item.Quantity; costo = costo + item.Total; }
            }

            listItem.Add(item.Pdv);
            listItem.Add(item.Pla_ID);
            listItem.Add(item.Price);


            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
            {
                var value = 0;
                int month = item.Fecha.Month;
                if (item.Fecha.Day == i)
                {
                    value = (int)item.Quantity;  listItem.Add(value.ToString());
                }
                value = 0;
                listItem.Add(value.ToString());
            }

            listItem.Add((item.Quantity).ToString());

            listItem.Add(item.price * item.Quantity);

        }
```

however this give methe quantity for each dish asigned to each day but in a diferent line giving me a 3 result lines for "Pla_Id=65", and 5 Lines for "Pla_Id=70" each has the quantity on their corresponding day but it should be only 1 line for each diferent dish not for each diferent day,

How can i acomplish this?

Comment: This would be far easier if you create a model with properties `string Pdv`, `int Pla_ID`, `decimal Price` and `List<int> Days`

Comment: stil if i make a model like that how could i get the desire result? if my table has the data as the example i show

Comment: thank you in advance @StephenMuecke having a hard time figuring this out ><

Comment: This needs Grouping of Data, need to GroupBy using `pdv` and `pla_id`, then the IGrouping will contain all the data you need to get the required shape

Comment: In fact no grouping is causing issue in your current code, you may want to fill a Structure like Dictionary out there too, similar to way I have done using Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a following model to Answer this question:

// Main model Dishes class

```
public class Dishes
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set;}

    public string Pdv { get; set;}

    public int Pla_ID { get; set;}

    public int Quantity { get; set;}

    public double Price { get; set;}

    public double Total { get; set;}    
}
```

// Processing Logic

- Create a Grouping based on fields `Pdv`, `Pla_Id` and `Price` as follows:

  ```
    var dishesGrouping = 
    dishes.GroupBy(d => new {d.Pdv,d.Pla_ID,d.Price});
  ```

Based on the understanding that `Price` will also remain constant for a combination of `Pdv`, `Pla_Id`, as I can see in your data or otherwise Price need to move out of the Key and would be part of Day wise structure like Quantity.

- Now create a following `DataStructure`

  ```
  var dishGroupingDictionary = dishesGrouping
                           .ToDictionary(dishGrp => dishGrp.Key, dishGrp =>
                           {
                              var dishDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

                              for(int i=1; i<=30;i++)
                                 dishDictionary[i] = 0;

                               foreach (var grp in dishGrp)
                               {
                                  dishDictionary[grp.Fecha.Day] = 
                                  grp.Quantity;
                               }

                              return dishDictionary;
                           });
  ```
- This will create data in the format: `Dictionary<Anonymous(string,int,double),Dictionary<int,int>>`
- Now you have a structure will all the information required for further processing to provide an example:
- Outer Dictionary has a Key as combination of `Pdv`,`Pla_ID` and `Price`, which is the unique combination required
- Inner Dictionary contains Day Wise data for `Quantity`, All the Dates are filled with 0 default and is updated for the available dates in each Group Key.
- Now each `Key-Value` Pair would contain the Unique combination of `Pdv`,`Pla_ID` and `Price`, Day wise quantities can be added via inner Dictionary and Price can be multiplied for total. All the remaining Days shall be 0 by default.

// Following is the simple data printing logic. You may even plan to store it in a different and flatter `model` for quick usage, but its preferred to keep Day wise data in a collection like `Dictionary`, since its easy to extend and modify, which is not simple for `model`.

```
foreach (var kv in dishGroupingDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pdv:{0},Pla_Id:    
    {1},Price{2}",kv.Key.Pdv,kv.Key.Pla_ID,kv.Key.Price);

    int totalQuantity = kv.Value.Sum(x => x.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("Total Quantity: {0}", totalQuantity);

    double totalPrice = totalQuantity * kv.Key.Price;

    Console.WriteLine("Total Price: {0}", totalPrice);

  // Day wise data printing:        
  foreach(var kvChild in kv.Value)
    Console.WriteLine("Day:{0},Quantity:{1}",kvChild.Key,kvChild.Value);        

}
```

Comment: This answer was very explicit and very good in a way that i could understant enterely how to succed on my problem, the only problem i had implementing this is that isntead of printing the values in dishGroupDiccionary , i tried to save them into a list wich caused an error on my aplication "the specify conversion is not valid"
otherwise this was a very good answer and i thank you @Mrinal for showing me how to do it correctly

Comment: Welcome @ArturoMartinez, glad my solution helped in better understanding of the logic. Do let me know if something is still not clear. This is more about usage of correct collection to solve an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a view model which represents the data you want to display

```
public class DishVM
{
    public string Pdv { get; set; }
    public int Pla_ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<int> Days { get; set; }
    public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Dishes> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming your querying the data for a particular month/year, to make this more flexible, assign the days in the month to a variable, say `int daysInMonth` (using the [DateTime.DaysInMonth()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) method).

To generate a collection of the view model

```
var data = db.Dishes.Where(...).ToList(); // your query
int daysInMonth = 31; // hard coded for November 2016

// Group the data and initialize the collection of days for each group
var model = data.GroupBy(x => new { Pdv = x.Pdv, Pla_ID = x.Pla_ID, Price = x.Price })
    .Select(x => new DishVM()
    {
        Pdv = x.Key.Pdv,
        Pla_ID = x.Key.Pla_ID,
        Price = x.Key.Price,
        Days = new List<int>(new int[daysInMonth]),
        Data = x
    }).ToList();
// Assign the quantity for each day
foreach (var record in model)
{
    foreach(var dish in record.Data)
    {  
        int index = dish.Fecha.Day - 1;
        record.Days[index] = dish.Quantity;
        record.TotalQuantity += dish.Quantity;
    }
    record.TotalPrice = record.TotalQuantity * record.Price;
}
```